# Which Linux distro to pick for volunteering?

Tags: distribution, linux-development

The number of Linux distributions is large.  Someone wanting to volunteer with one of them might have a hard time picking between them, because it's hard to sense the culture, environment, and level of community and esprit de corp.  Also, some might be very strict with long processes before you are trusted, or else much looser with a smaller community with more trust.  It's hard to tell where to look for information.  Maybe one is in great need, and others are well-established with less need.  How would I find out who is in greatest need?

Joining a Linux distribution's team of writers, developers, testers, coordinators, and administrators is a big decision.  This is an extremely sensitive question, and I hope nobody is slighted by either the question or responses.

Comment: This entirely depends on what aspect of the distro you want to work on.

Comment: This must be a language thing, but what exactly do you mean under "for volunteering"? You have a volunteering group of some kind and you're finding them a distro or ...?? (not mocking you; serious question here).

Comment: Thinking, first help write docs/manuals, then help test, then help fix bugs, maybe help maintain a package.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com seems like a better fit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [DistroWatch](http://distrowatch.com/) for a comprehensive list of Linux distros. You will find many not known distros that might need help.

After you established a good reputation, you can try to switch to another famous distro like Fedora or Arch Linux.

On a side note, the book "The Linux Programming Interface" is amazingly useful resource.

Comment: That's a great approach to get in the door, and thanks for the book reference.